# XPath: how to find a class above class

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to access class above 'glyphicon-cog' class (second span).

I have something like that, but it doesn't work: 
//span[@class='k-link']//span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog cursor-pointer']

The HTML code:

```
<li class="k-item k-state-default k-last" role="menuitem" id="chartHeaderButtons_mn_active" style="z-index: auto;">
<span class="k-link">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog cursor-pointer"></span>
    <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s"></span>
</span>

<div class="k-animation-container" style="width: 171px; height: 26px; margin-left: -2px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px; padding-bottom: 4px; overflow: hidden; display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 10002; top: 30px; left: -139px;">

    <ul class="k-group k-menu-group k-popup k-reset" role="menu" data-role="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: normal; transform: translateY(-26px);">

        <li class="k-item k-state-default k-first k-last" role="menuitem" id="previousInstallationsOption">
            <span class="k-link">
                <input id="show-previous-installations" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isPreviousInstallation">
                <label for="show-previous-installations">
                    <b>Previous installations</b>
                </label>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use /..

```
//span[@class='k-link']//span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog cursor-pointer']/..
```

or ancestor

```
//span[@class='k-link']//span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog cursor-pointer']//ancestor::span
```